# Pycharm IDE does not see a multistring containing SQL as a string

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

So I am just following a tutorial on Scrapy, once I got to the part where I need to try to save scraped data in my DB, at the point where I had to create a new class inside pipelines.py I am getting this "bug".. Why does Pycharm not see this as a multi-string and highlights what I have typed in?? Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried hovering over it? Pycharm usually detects SQL inside strings (which you can see as it has syntax highlighted the string), so it might just be complaining about your SQL dialect not being defined.

Comment: Please share the exact warning that PyCharm shows you when you hover, or use the lightbulb.

Comment: Added more screenshots